# C++: CkSpider.h giving linker errors

Tags: c++, gcc, web-crawler, linker-errors

I am trying to make a web crawler in c++. I am using CkSpider.h in my code but it is giving liker errors-

> [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x14):
>   undefined reference to `CkSpider::CkSpider()'     [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x1f):
>   undefined reference to`CkStringArray::CkStringArray()'     [Linker
>   error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x2a):
>   undefined reference to `CkStringArray::CkStringArray()'     [Linker
>   error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x3d):
>   undefined reference to`CkStringArray::put_Unique(bool)'     [Linker
>   error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x50):
>   undefined reference to `CkStringArray::put_Unique(bool)'     [Linker
>   error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x63):
>   undefined reference to`CkStringArray::Append(char const*)'
>   [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x79):
>   undefined reference to `CkSpider::AddAvoidOutboundLinkPattern(char
>   const*)'     [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x8f):
>   undefined reference to`CkSpider::AddAvoidOutboundLinkPattern(char
>   const*)'     [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0xa5):
>   undefined reference to `CkSpider::AddAvoidOutboundLinkPattern(char
>   const*)'     [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0xbb):
>   undefined reference to`CkSpider::AddAvoidOutboundLinkPattern(char
>   const*)'     [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0xd1):
>   undefined reference to `CkSpider::AddAvoidOutboundLinkPattern(char
>   const*)'     more undefined references to`
>   CkSpider::AddAvoidOutboundLinkPattern(char const*)' follow
>   [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0xfd):
>   undefined reference to `CkSpider::put_CacheDir(char const*)'
>
>   [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x113):
>   undefined reference to`CkSpider::put_FetchFromCache(bool)'
>   [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x129):
>   undefined reference to `CkSpider::put_UpdateCache(bool)'     [Linker
>   error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x139):
>   undefined reference to`CkStringArray::pop()'     [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x151):
>   undefined reference to `CkSpider::Initialize(char const*)'     [Linker
>   error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x166):
>   undefined reference to`CkSpider::getUrlDomain(char const*)'
>   [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x17e):
>   undefined reference to `CkSpider::getBaseDomain(char const*)'
>
>   [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x18d):
>   undefined reference to`CkStringArray::Append(char const*)'
>   [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x1a4):
>   undefined reference to `CkSpider::CrawlNext()'     [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x1bf):
>   undefined reference to`CkSpider::lastUrl()'     [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x1d5):
>   undefined reference to `CkSpider::get_LastFromCache()'     [Linker
>   error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x1f2):
>   undefined reference to`CkSpider::SleepMs(long)'     [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x224):
>   undefined reference to `CkSpider::getOutboundLink(long)'     [Linker
>   error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x23c):
>   undefined reference to`CkSpider::getUrlDomain(char const*)'
>   [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x254):
>   undefined reference to `CkSpider::getBaseDomain(char const*)'
>
>   [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x269):
>   undefined reference to`CkStringArray::Contains(char const*)'
>   [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x282):
>   undefined reference to `CkStringArray::Append(char const*)'
>
>   [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x28d):
>   undefined reference to`CkStringArray::get_Count()'     [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x2aa):
>   undefined reference to `CkSpider::get_NumOutboundLinks()'     [Linker
>   error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x2c7):
>   undefined reference to`CkStringArray::get_Count()'     [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x2df):
>   undefined reference to `CkStringArray::~CkStringArray()'     [Linker
>   error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x2ea):
>   undefined reference to`CkStringArray::~CkStringArray()'     [Linker
>   error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x2f8):
>   undefined reference to `CkSpider::~CkSpider()'     [Linker error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x30e):
>   undefined reference to`CkStringArray::~CkStringArray()'     [Linker
>   error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x31d):
>   undefined reference to `CkStringArray::~CkStringArray()'     [Linker
>   error]
>   C:\Users\amit\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5VFW0.o:webcrawler.cpp:(.text+0x32f):
>   undefined reference to`CkSpider::~CkSpider()'     In function `main':
>   [Linker error] C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\src\mingwrt/../mingw/main.c:73:
>   undefined reference to`WinMain@16'     ld returned 1 exit status

Git link of the Ckspider library [Ckspider.h](https://github.com/hwrod/employee_screen_tracker/blob/master/ckhttp/include/CkSpider.h)

My code-

```
#include<windows.h>
#include <CkSpider.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

#include <CkStringArray.h>

using namespace std;

void ChilkatSample(void)
    {

    CkSpider spider;

    CkStringArray seenDomains;
    CkStringArray seedUrls;

    seenDomains.put_Unique(true);
    seedUrls.put_Unique(true);


    seedUrls.Append("http://www.techxxx.org/");


    spider.AddAvoidOutboundLinkPattern("*?id=*");
    spider.AddAvoidOutboundLinkPattern("*.mypages.*");
    spider.AddAvoidOutboundLinkPattern("*.personal.*");
    spider.AddAvoidOutboundLinkPattern("*.comcast.*");
    spider.AddAvoidOutboundLinkPattern("*.aol.*");
    spider.AddAvoidOutboundLinkPattern("*~*");


    spider.put_CacheDir("c:/spiderCache/");
    spider.put_FetchFromCache(true);
    spider.put_UpdateCache(true);

    while (seedUrls.get_Count() > 0) {

        const char * url;
        url = seedUrls.pop();
        spider.Initialize(url);

        const char * domain;
        domain = spider.getUrlDomain(url);
        seenDomains.Append(spider.getBaseDomain(domain));

        long i;
        bool success;
        for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            success = spider.CrawlNext();
            if (success != true) {
                break;
            }

            printf("%s\n",spider.lastUrl());


            if (spider.get_LastFromCache() != true) {
                spider.SleepMs(1000);
            }

        }

        for (i = 0; i <= spider.get_NumOutboundLinks() - 1; i++) {

            url = spider.getOutboundLink(i);

            domain = spider.getUrlDomain(url);
            const char * baseDomain;
            baseDomain = spider.getBaseDomain(domain);
            if (!seenDomains.Contains(baseDomain)) {
                seedUrls.Append(url);
            }

            if (seedUrls.get_Count() > 1000) {
                break;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Help.

Comment: You're probably missing linking with whatever library the implementation of the code in Ckspider.h is in.

Comment: Are you linking to the corresponding code (presumably CkSpider.cpp or a library that contains it)?

Comment: yes, edited my question and also provided the code.

Comment: @AmitTripathi, what's missing is not in your code. `#include` does not mean that the CkSpider implementation is added to your program, that only means that the *compiler* can know about the definition of the classes/types/etc. provided by CkSpider... and leave a *hole* for those. However that *hole* can only be plugged when the executable is *linked*. And it needs to be plugged with the library or *.o file that contains the implementation of the library. That information needs to be passed in the command line of the linker.

Comment: @jsantander can you please tell me how to link *.o file or provide me some link from where I can implement it. I am using DEV C++.

Comment: @AmitTripathi I'm not familiar with Dev C++. I could guess it has some concept of a *project*. It probably has somewhere you can specify the properties of a project, and where you can define what libraries (and where are those libraries located) are required to complete your program.